# interact.js disable native scoll

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, interact.js

I would like develop a VueJS swip cards app but interactJS disable the y-axis native scroll on mobile. I reproduce my app on this codepen : https://codepen.io/ostaladaFab/pen/LYQBvXm/7acc1eb6e6afb3583c7f65133019f64d.
I can't scroll anymore on mobile. A solution ?

The shorter url : https://shorturl.at/dAS14

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Remove these two lines of CSS from your code, and the scrolling issue should be gone.

```css
-ms-touch-action: none;
    touch-action: none;
```

For these two lines, your touches are being ignored.

Comment: Oh thanks Obaydur Rahman. Of course. I used touch-action to fix an other issue. Without `touch-action: none`, cards was not swipping on chrome mobile. But with `touch-action: pan-y`, the two issues are fixed. 

Thanks again.

Comment: I'm late, but thanks Obaydur :)